# Windows 10 - ShutdownBlockReasonCreate causes shutdown to be canceled after one minute

Tags: winapi, windows-10

My application may sometimes need to perform longer tasks during shutdown. So it vetoes the shutdown by processsing WM_QUERYENDSESSION with a result value of 0, and uses ShutdownBlockReasonCreate to display a meaningful message during the black shutdown-wait screen that Windows shows when an application prevents the shutdown.

However, since Windows 10, this black screen is shown only for one minute. After that, the shutdown is canceled and the user is returned to the desktop. Why is this so, and can the black screen's life be extended indefinitely, as it was under Windows 7? The black screen should be shown until all shutdown block reasons are destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

A long-running task is meant to block shutdown from occurring *before* shutdown is initiated.  If you have a task that does not want to be interrupted by shutdown, the task needs to call `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()` at the beginning and call `ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy()` when finished.  The user can still *force* the shutdown, though.

But once shutdown has been initiated, it cannot be blocked, and it can be extended for only a short period of time before the OS intervenes to force shutdown.  Shutdown is a bad time to *start* a new long-running task, if you can avoid it.

Refer to MSDN for more details:

[Application Shutdown Changes in Windows Vista](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677.aspx)

[Changes to power management in Windows Vista](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070416-00/?p=27243)

[Now that Windows makes it harder for your program to block shutdown, how do you block shutdown?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120614-00/?p=7373)

At the very least, if you need a longer period of time to run a task at shutdown, you should call `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()` when you receive `WM_QUERYENDESSION` and return TRUE to let shutdown continue, and then run the task when you receive `WM_ENDSESSION`.  Do not block `WM_QUERYENDESSION` for more than a few seconds, or else Windows will be more likely to intervene and terminate your app immeidately.

This is also important because shutdown might not actually proceed after your app responds TRUE to `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`.  When `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` is sent, Windows is asking your app for permission to shutdown (or telling it that shutdown is about to be forced), but it is not actually shutting down yet.  When your app receives `WM_ENDSESSION`, then it knows shutdown is actually being performed (and why).  This flow is also described on MSDN:

[Shutdown Changes for Windows Vista](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb394721.aspx)

[Restart Manager | Guidelines for Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373651.aspx)

Even if you follow these guidelines, Windows is still not going to let you block shutdown indefinitely.  It might give you an extra 30 seconds, 1 minute, etc.  Your app's shutdown logic needs to be as fast as possible, and if that means you will have to redesign your shutdown logic to speed it up, then do it.

Comment: Many thanks! I will check what can be done. The use case is that customers want to run backup jobs on shut down. The time they take may vary. I guess I will recommend letting the application invoke the shutdown, rather than letting the shutdown invoke the application.